# Find records which are not exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, exists

I've this table structure:

-request
request_id
user_id

-user
user_id
company_id

-company
company_id

I want to select all those records from requests table where user_id=? and no such records where the company id of to users is same.

Comment: SELECT * FROM request WHERE user_id NOT IN(SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_id=123)

Comment: `if user_id=123 and other user_id=456 for both users the company_id=999, so I want only those requests for user_id=123 from requests where user_id=456 has no entry in request table.` care to explain what this means please?

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: @JayKazama, edited the question. That was just example.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually achieved using LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT r.*
FROM request r
JOIN user u ON r.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN u1 ON u1.user_id != u.user_id AND u1.company_id = u.company_id
LEFT JOIN request r1 ON r1.user_id = u1.user_id
WHERE r1.user_id IS NULL
```

By "where" we say that we don't want "users with same company, who has at least 1 request"